# MYSQL select option values question? Number or String?

Tags: mysql

Just a quick question.

I am developing a php / mysql custom event page. I am stuck on the Select Values when "submitting a record" ??

This is what I have now:

```
<select name="event_type" id="dis1">
                    <option value="Mtn. Bike">Mtn. Bike</option>
                    <option value="Road">Road</option>
                    <option value="Cyclocross">Cyclocross</option>
                </select>
```

Is this sufficient?

Should I do something like this instead?

```
 <select name="event_type" id="dis1">
                        <option value="1">Mtn. Bike</option>
                        <option value="2">Road</option>
                        <option value="3">Cyclocross</option>
                    </select>
```

Not sure if it really matters, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a numeric representation. It is more elegant when these are foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without knowing how you are using the data.

Generally speaking, if you're...

- Sending an email, then the first is *easiest*.
- Saving to a relational database), the second option is preferred.